# Importing constants are undefined react redux

Tags: es6-modules

I have something like this:

```
//ActionTypes.js
export const a = 'a';

//Reducer.js
import a from './ActionTypes';
//export reducer function that uses string a

//Actions.js
import a from './ActionTypes';
return {type: a, data: 'something'}
```

but in both reducer.js and actions.js 'a' is undefined. There is no circular dependancy as far as i know. Pls help

Comment: have you tried `import {a} from '...'`?

Comment: Since you're using named exports you have use named imports syntax: `import { a } from './ActionTypes'`, or `import * as actionTypes from './ActionTypes'; actionTypes.a` if you'd prefer to have one object with all action types

Comment: That works. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I would export `a` with curly braces like so:

```
import { a } from './ActionTypes'
```

`a` is a named export because you gave it a variable name when you declared it like this:

`export const a = 'a';`

The syntax for importing named exports necessitate the use of `{}`.
The syntax that you've used apply to default exports. See below for an example:

```
export default function a() {
  return 'a';
};
```

Default exports would not work for constants because you would want to declare a name for the variables. You may not use `var`, `let` or `const` with `export default`.

For more info, please see [MDN docs for export](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/web/javascript/reference/statements/export)

One other thing, it is convention to use ALLCAPS when naming constants.